# Grunt copy task can not retain directory structure

Tags: gruntjs, bower, grunt-contrib-copy

I am using `Bower` to install the dependencies of my project and grab only the files I need with `Grunt.js` and copy them to the `static` to be served by the application.

One of them is the `MathJax` library but when I try to copy the whole folder (see the code below) it just ignores the directories and sprays all the files into the destination without handling the `MathJax` directory structure.

```
copy: {
    MathJax: {
        expand: true,
        flatten: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/MathJax/',
        src: ['**'],
        dest: 'base/static/MathJax/'
    }
}
```

Is it a common bug on the `copy` task of `Grunt` or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you just copy the files over or you also uglify them? I just need the bare minimum of MathJax and I don't want to upload a lot of unneeded files to my server.

Comment: In my case I just copy all the files but in your case maybe it's wiser to exclude some subfolders like `src: ['!MathJax/[folder_name]/**']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the `flatten` options which does what it says; flattens the directory structure.

See docs: [Building the files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

Comment: Oh, I'm using the `flatten` option for some other tasks and forgot to remove it even though I've looked into it. (silly question but anyway thanks!)